# Remove columns from list object out of a class c#

Tags: c#, list, class, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need the possiblity to create Code in C# like this

```
public class SummaryA 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surename { get: set; }
    public int age { get; set;}
}
```

now I create an list object from the class SummaryA

```
List<SummaryA> list1= new List<SummaryA>();
```

yet I need the possibility to remove the column age from the list Summary, anyone have ideas?
I need this for some more columns, so I wish the list was dynamically or some things else.

sry for my bad english.

Comment: So you want to set all the values for age to zero? Otherwise you will need another class that doesn't have the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely remove the column you really need another class to store the data in, for example:

```
public class AgelessSummaryA 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surename { get: set; }
}
```

And now you can project the first list into a new list of this class with Linq and [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<AgelessSummaryA> agelessSummaries = ageSummaries
    .Select(s => new AgelessSummaryA
    {
        name = s.name,
        surename = s.surename
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use it for in a grid or for some display i guess, then you can use anonymous types where you can shape the data the way you like:

```
var projectedList = (from l in list1
                     select new
                     {
                         name = l.name,
                         surename  = l.surename 
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: In this case I have to declare before all needed columns in a select, but I talk over 200 columns they could be dynamically.

Comment: @S.Sire So you want to provide property names as strings and exclude those from the result object ?